# Can we combine set notation and interval notation?

Tags: notation

Is it possible for us to combine set notation and interval notation, e. g. $x \in \{3, 10\}$?

Comment: What you've written looks like standard set notation to me. And since intervals are sets, "interval notation" arguably is just a specialized type of set notation. Which part of your example did you think was "interval notation"?

Comment: $x\in\{3,10\}$ means $x=3$ or $x=10$; $x\in(3,10)$ means $3\lt x\lt10$

Comment: Your question is unclear to me.  How are you "combining" set notation and interval notation?